# Random Background at the Ready

Tags: javascript, random, background

This is really simple, but I'm not a programmer. I just brute force code with general problem solving skills. It's not workin' for this. This code is set to randomize the background image, and it works. However, it's set to wait until the page loads completely, so its timing is too inconsistent. As I understand it, document.ready would give me more consistent (and quicker) timing with it, but I can't seem to make it work. Here's the working version:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    function changeImg(imgNumber) { 
        var myImages = [
            "http://static.tumblr.com/0obftwk/u0Am8xfjf/streetarturbaninphilade.jpg",
            "http://static.tumblr.com/0obftwk/Xmym8xfet/artmuseumarea.jpg",
            "http://static.tumblr.com/0obftwk/znNm8xf9e/rowhouseswestphilly.jpg",
            "http://static.tumblr.com/0obftwk/af1m8xf87/phillyvista.jpg",
            "http://static.tumblr.com/0obftwk/ydIm8xf74/chinagatephiladelphia.jpg",
            "http://static.tumblr.com/0obftwk/8kCm8xf41/broadritner.jpg"
        ]; 
        var imgShown = document.body.style.backgroundImage; 
        var newImgNumber =Math.floor(Math.random()*myImages.length);
        document.body.style.backgroundImage = 'url('+myImages[newImgNumber]+')'; 
    }   

    window.onload=changeImg;
</script>
```

Comment: You probably want `document.onload` rather than `window.onload`

Comment: Perhaps you can put in inline right after the body tag and call changeImg() right then and there, instead of attaching it to an event handler that happens (too) late. Cool images, btw.

Comment: Thanks, Endophage, but simply changing 'window' to 'document' didn't work. Perhaps there's more to your proposal than what I interpreted. // Chelmerisch, first, those images are "Lorem ipsum" for a (Tumblr-based) site I'm buildin' about Philly. They aren't mine, and I'll replace them when I have my own suitable images. As for your proposal, I get the concept, but I'm not sure how I would execute it. Before I posted here, I tried simply removing the onLoad, but the script stopped workin' completely. Again, I'm not  a programmer and don't have the background knowledge to understand why.

Answer (score 0):

If the list of images is known before you load the page, stick the references to your image in the CSS, and then just change the className on document.body

```
.bgClass1 {background-image: url(http://static.tumblr.com/0obftwk/u0Am8xfjf/streetarturbaninphilade.jpg)}
```

... and so on...

```
<body class="bgClass1">
```

Otherwise, build a preloader with js

Comment: Hmm...If I understand this at all, you're proposition means a simpler script that pretty much randomizes the clas of 'body'. That the gist of it? If so, is there a simple reason why that's preferable?

Comment: You can rely on the CSS to do the loading of the images instead of mucking around with javascript preloaders - you essentially get around the issue you are having with it not loading. Again, this will only work if you know the images you are including. Good luck!